# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel

Estoy iniciando una aplicacion y da este fallo cuando ejecuto el metodo store

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel_apirestfull`.`vehiculos`, CONSTRAINT `vehiculos_fabricantes_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`fabricantes_id`) REFERENCES `fabricantes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `vehiculos` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-02-10 11:50:30, 2017-02-10 11:50:30))
```

MIS MIGRACIONES HASTA AHORA

VEHICULOS

```
  class CreateVehiculosTable extends Migration {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('vehiculos',function(Blueprint $table){

                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('color');
                $table->float('cilindraje');
                $table->integer('potencia');
                $table->float('peso');
                  $table->timestamps();  

                $table->integer('fabricantes_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('fabricantes_id')->references('id')->on('fabricantes')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
           Schema::drop('vehiculos');
        } }
```

FABRICANTES

```
  class CreateFabricantesTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {

                Schema::create('fabricantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre');
                 $table->string('telefono');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::drop('fabricantes');
        }
    }
```

MODELO VEHICULO

```
namespace App\modelos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class vehiculo extends Model
{
  protected  $table = 'vehiculos';

  protected  $fillable = ['color','cilindraje','potencia','peso','fabricantes_id'];

  protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

   public function fabricante()
   {
     return $this->BelongsTo('\App\modelos\fabricante');
   }
}
```

MODELO FABRICANTE

```
class fabricante extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'fabricantes';

   protected $fillable = ['nombre','telefono'];

   protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function vehiculos()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('\App\modelos\vehiculo','fabricantes_id');
   }
}
```

CONTROLADOR, METODO STORE

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$request->color or !$request->cilindraje or !$request->potencia or !$request->peso):
            return response()->Json(['Notificacion ' => 'Todos los datos son obligatorios, por favor introducelos'],422);
        endif;

        vehiculo::create([$request->all()]);
          return response()->Json(['Notificacion ' => 'Vehiculo creado correctamente'],200);
    }
```

DATABASE SEEDER

```
  public function run()
    {

        $this->call(fabricantesseeder::class);
        $this->call(vehiculosseeder::class);
    }
```

No me explico por que puede dar el fallo, la relacion es correcta el campo id que pruebo a introducir en el campo fabricante_id existe en la tabla vehiculos como id.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: No estas asignando el valor fabricantes_id en la insercion por lo que salta la restriccion de la FK (el propio error te indica el insert que generas-> insert into `vehiculos` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en el método store.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if(!$request->color or !$request->cilindraje or !$request->potencia or !$request->peso):
        return response()->Json(['Notificacion ' => 'Todos los datos son obligatorios, por favor introducelos'],422);
    endif;

    vehiculo::create([$request->all()]);
      return response()->Json(['Notificacion ' => 'Vehiculo creado correctamente'],200);
}
```

Específicamente en la esta parte:

```
vehiculo::create([$request->all()]);
```

El método `$request->all()` ya te devuelve un array. Es por eso que el método create, que espera un array, construye mal el insert al no encontrar los campos definidos en la propiedad `$fillable`. Al final le estás pasando al método create algo así:

```
vehiculo::create([[...]]);
```

Para solucionarlo solo borra los `[]`. Debería quedar así:

```
vehiculo::create($request->all());
```

Saludos!

Comment: Pues si, si era eso, no lo habia visto, pero tampoco me habia planteado que el error podia venir de ahi, ya he tenido ese error en otros proyectos y nunca ha sido por enviar mal el array. siempre se aprende algo nuevo. En fin, muchas gracias, habia tocado ya tantas opciones que se me acababan las ideas. De nuevo gracias y un saludo.